# Integrate react-native with signalr on the server

Tags: react-native, notifications, signalr

I'm new in react-native and i'm trying to integrate my application with backend Signalr service it works with mvc project but i can't implement the same logic
 in react native 
there's no [.client.notify] function in react-native how to implement it 
I have installed signalr plugin to my application but i need to figure out how to use it with my current signalr service 
any tutorial or example of such task would be appreciated